# Sonar Report error: Report refers to a file which is not configured as a test file

Tags: sonarqube

I was using the -D option since I don't have access to the sonar properties file itself.

/home/....../src/ contains both sum.js and sum.test.js files.

/home/.../reports/test-reporter.xml

```
`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><testExecutions version="1"><file path="/home/....../src/sum.test.js"><testCase name="sum" duration="4"/></file></testExecutions>`

mvn sonar:sonar
-Dsonar.testExecutionReportPaths=/home/.../reports/test-reporter.xml
-Dsonar.host.url=https://xxx
-Dsonar.login=xxx

mvn sonar:sonar
-Dsonar.testExecutionReportPaths=/home/.../reports/test-reporter.xml
-Dsonar.host.url=https://xxx
-Dsonar.login=xxx
-Dsonar.tests=src
-Dsonar.test.inclusions=src/**/*.test.js
```

Both of the above commands fails with same error
Error: Line 3 of report refers to a file which is not configured as a test file:

Answer (score 4):

i know this is maybe late to answer, but i went through the same problem, and i could solve it this way, hope it can help someone.

What helped me solve this, was adding the following properties to the `sonar-project.properties` file:

```
sonar.tests ={{project folder}}/__tests__
sonar.test.inclusions={{project folder}}/__tests__/*.test.ts
```

Here you should replace those values with the name of the folder your project is in. Take into account, if your directory is already pointing to inside of your project folder. avoid those values. The key here is to include this properties pointing to the right path.

Note that my tests are in the **test** folder. point the sonar.tests property to the folder where your tests are, and the sonar.test.inclusions to inside of it.

Comment: Thanks!!!
In addition to the above properties, I included sonar.sources and we are able to see the code coverage now..